# How to get data from a non-member function into a member function in Qt?

Tags: c++, qt, callback, signals-slots

I have a Qt project (in Win10) that requires a non-member function in my MainWindow cpp file. It's a callback function that is triggered automatically from an external library when data from an attached sensor arrives. I like to display this data on a MainWindow widget (a plainTextEdit), but of course I cannot access any MainWindow elements from my callback function, and also no signal-slot concept works so far. Below is a minimal example of the problem:

MainWindow.h:

```
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H

#include <QMainWindow>
#include <QMutex>

QT_BEGIN_NAMESPACE
namespace Ui { class MainWindow; }
QT_END_NAMESPACE

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    MainWindow(QWidget *parent = nullptr);
    ~MainWindow();

    void displayData();

private:
    Ui::MainWindow *ui;
};
#endif // MAINWINDOW_H
```

MainWindow.cpp:

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"

// define global variables
QMutex mutex;
bool new_data_arrived = false;
QString newDataStr;

void newData() {
// This is a callback function triggered when data from a sensor attached via USB arrives
// I want to pass the result as a QString to MainWindow::displayData() to display it on screen 
    mutex.lock();
    new_data_arrived = true;
    newDataStr = "new data";
    mutex.unlock();
};

void MainWindow::displayData()
{
    mutex.lock();
    if (new_data_arrived == true) {
        new_data_arrived = false;
        ui->plainTextEdit->appendPlainText(newDatastr);
    }  
    mutex.unlock();
}

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent)
    : QMainWindow(parent)
    , ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}
```

The function `MainWindow::displayData()` is then running in a loop (but that’s unimportant for my problem, so I removed it from the minimal example above…).

As mentioned, `newData()` cannot access any elements of MainWindow, which is clear. The only workaround I found so far is to use global variables as shown above, to get data from the non-member function `newData()` into the member function `displayData()`. I also included a mutex to avoid possible share violation (no idea if that's necessary, but it doesn't harm...).

Is there a more elegant way? In principle, what I need is either a signal-slot concept, but `newData()` cannot emit signals of MainWindow, or to get `this` into the function `newData()`, so that ui elements can be accessed.

Comment: Why cannot `newData()` access `MainWindow`? If you make the main window globally accessible - e.g. as static variable or via singleton pattern, then it can be accessed. Maybe I am missing something...

Btw. where do you set `newData()` to be used as callback? If you locate this point in code, you can easily inject some lambda or functor which cann access `MainWindow` without need of static variable or singleton.

This seems to me as https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem question.

Comment: @V.K. The solution seems to be close to what you suggest: I have now a pointer to the main window as a global variable, which allows me to use the signal-slot-mechanism inside the static function (I made displayData() a slot and tried to use emit... works!).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use QMetaObject::invokeMethod to call a slot of a QObject from a non  QObject slot (your callback funtion).

Here is an example:

```
class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT
    //...
    
public slots:
    void displayData( QString szNewData );
};


//Cpp MainWindow.cpp file
static MainWindow * mainWindowObj = nullptr;

void setMainWindowObj( MainWindow * ptr ){
    mainWindowObj = ptr;
}

void newData() {
    // This is a callback function triggered when data from a sensor attached via USB arrives
    // I want to pass the result as a QString to MainWindow::displayData() to display it on screen 

    if( mainWindowObj == nullptr )
        return;
        
    QMetaObject::invokeMethod( mainWindowObj, //pointer to MainWindow instance (see main.cpp)
                               "displayData", //slot name
                               Qt::QueuedConnection, //connection type
                               Q_ARG( QString, newDataStr ) ); //Param passed to the slot
};

void MainWindow::displayData( QString szNewData )
{
    ui->plainTextEdit->appendPlainText( szNewData );
}


//main.cpp file or where MainWindow instance is initialized

void setMainWindowObj( MainWindow * ptr );

int main( int argc, char *argv[] ){

    //....
    QApplication app(argc, argv);
    
    //....
    MainWindow mainWindow;
    setMainWindowObj ( &mainWindow );
    
    //....
}
```

Comment: Many thanks, that works perfectly! (Note, I received 2 compiler errors and corrected 2 typos in your answer: invokeMethod instead InvokeMethod and QueuedConnection instead QueueConnection). Thanks a lot!

Comment: I do not get this complicated solution. Why cannot I just call `displayData()` directly?

Comment: @CharlesTucker3 Thanks for the edited solution. I've created the solution in the fly without Qt Creator.

Comment: @V.K. It's just a Qt way to solve the problem, invokeMethod create a queued call to displayData slot, that will be done in the event loop of thread holding MainWindow instance. This mecanisme avoid polling for data ready or concurrent data access